# What does mean "IMPACT LEVEL CHANGED FROM 2 TO 3"? What difference between impact level 2 and level 3?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have this message on email from crash analitics. 
It used in code next way in application class:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

in gradle used:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

May be I have this message after autoincrement io.fabric version. I don't now exactly.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the related crash is repeated a lot. Please check http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92525-what-are-those-impact-bars-on-the-issue-list